# Backpack Editable Columns does not store data with a wrapper

Tags: wrapper, laravel-10, laravel-backpack

I like to flag objectionable data to users.
But if I use the wrapper, the Editable Columns won't save the data. After pressing enter it returns 404 - Page not found. The route admin/undefined could not be found.:

`CRUD::addColumn([name'=> 'serial_number',label'=> 'Ser. čsl.',type'=> 'editable_text', select_on_click'  => true, save_on_focusout' => true, 'min_width'=> '50px',wrapper'=> ['element' => 'span','class' => function ($crud, $column, $entry, $related_key) {if ($entry->stock AND $entry->stock->serial_number_YN AND (is_null($entry->serial_number) OR $entry->serial_number=='VYPLNIT')                     ) return 'badge badge-success'; }, ],]);`

The wrapper works beautifully in list operation, but not so in Editable Columns.
Only without wrapper code works for me:

`CRUD::addColumn(['name'=> 'serial_number',label'=> 'Ser. čsl.',type'=> 'editable_text','select_on_click'=> true,save_on_focusout'=>true]);`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is as simple as that. Once the wrapper is applied, it fails to save changes.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is a bug, so i will open an issue to solve it.

Thanks.